# Counting and adding if some arrays has element at some index

Tags: bash, bash-array

Can the below code be easily achieved with minimum coding.

```
$ cluster1=(x y)
$ cluster2=(a b)
$ cluster3=(m)

$ my=$((${cluster1[0]+1}+${cluster2[0]+1}+${cluster2[0]+1}))

$ echo $my
3

$ my=$((${cluster1[1]+1}+${cluster2[1]+1}+${cluster3[1]+1}))
-bash: 1+1+: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")
```

Comment: You can't use the second element of an array of one.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping if it can somehow return 0 or some other value , if element doesn't exist

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I wanted to count how many arrays has elements at first index, same way on second index with one liner code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is generating a syntax error for each element that is not set.

```
$ echo "${cluster1[0]+1}+${cluster2[0]+1}+${cluster2[0]+1}"
1+1+1

$ echo "${cluster1[1]+1}+${cluster2[1]+1}+${cluster3[1]+1}"
1+1+
```

It would be better to count the set elements instead of trying to calculate with a generated expression in this case:

```
#!/bin/bash

cluster1=(x y)
cluster2=(a b)
cluster3=(m)

for (( i = 0; i < 3; ++i )); do
    is_set=( ${cluster1[i]+"1"} ${cluster2[i]+"1"} ${cluster3[i]+"1"} )
    printf 'i=%d:\t%d\n' "$i" "${#is_set[@]}"
done
```

This creates a new array, `is_set`, that will contain a `1` for each array that contains an element at index `i`.  The `1` is unimportant and could be any string.  The number of elements in the `is_set` array (`${#is_set[@]}`) is then the number of set elements from the `cluster` arrays at that index.

Testing:

```
$ bash script.sh
i=0:    3
i=1:    2
i=2:    0
```

Comment: nice... my=(${cluster1[1]+1} ${cluster2[1]+1} ${cluster3[1]+1}) ; echo ${#my[@]}

Answer (score 1):

May be a dirty trick, but how about prefixing a `0` (safe as the "Alternate Value" is a valid octal number):

```
my=$((0${cluster1[1]+1}+0${cluster2[1]+1}+0${cluster3[1]+1}))
echo $my
2
```

Comment: it's also nice..